# Passing Multiple Complex Objects in .Net Core From View To Controller

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to Post a form that should send an object that contains other object and lists of object, this objects might also contains other objects.

Example:

```cs
class Store{
    string Title;
    string Image;
    List<Classification> Classifications;
    Branch MainBranch;
    List<ContactInfo> StoreContact;
}

class Classification {
    int ID;
    string Title_AR;
    string Title_EN;
}

class Branch{
    string Title;
    Address MainAddress;
    List<ContactInfo> BranchContact;
}

class ContactInfo{
    ContactInfoType  ContactType;
    string  ContactValue;
}

class Address{
    City city;
    Locality locality;
    SubLocality sublocality;
}
```

I have added form in the view with all required fields and made it post to the controller, but not parsing the data to the complex objects and lists inside the object store (I know that I still need to edit the naming of inputs in HTML, but also it won't work)

This is the form in the View Page

```html
<form  asp-controller="Onboarding" asp-action="SaveBranch" method="post" 
  role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="wizard-validation">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-1 store-name">
            <label class="control-label">أسم المتجر</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 store-name">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="StoreTitle" 
              name="StoreTitle" value="البستان" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label class="control-label store-logo-lable">اضف<br>لوجو</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="store-logo-upload pull-right">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </div>
            <input class="hidden" type="file" id="file-simple" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group sup">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label class="control-label">جهات الاتصال</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-11 form-inline sup pull-left-i " id="klon1">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2 no-pad-lft">
                <select class="form-control select" style="display: none;" name="ContactType">
                    <option>تليفون</option>
                    <option>الايميل</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control SearchInput" name="Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group CloneBtn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label class="control-label">التصنيف</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select multiple class="form-control select" data-live-search="true" 
              title="اختر التصنيف"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4 class="add-branch-tit">أضافه فرع</h4>
    <hr class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="form-group sup">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label class="control-label">اسم الفرع</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group sup">
        <div class="col-md-1 sys-address-label">
            <label class="control-label">العنوان</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="row sys-address">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="SubLabel ">الدولة</label>
                    <select class="form-control select">
                        <option>مصر</option>
                        <option>فلسطين</option>
                        <option>السعودية</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="SubLabel ">المحافظة</label>
                    <select class="form-control select">
                        <option>القاهرة</option>
                        <option>فلسطين</option>
                        <option>السعودية</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="SubLabel ">المدينة</label>
                    <select class="form-control select">
                        <option>مدينة نصر</option>
                        <option>فلسطين</option>
                        <option>السعودية</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 sup">
                    <label class="SubLabel ">المنطقة</label>
                    <select class="form-control select">
                        <option>عباس العقاد</option>
                        <option>فلسطين</option>
                        <option>السعودية</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label class="SubLabel ">الشارع</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group sup">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label class="control-label">جهات الاتصال</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-11 form-inline sup pull-left-i" id="klon1">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2 no-pad-lft">
                <select class="form-control select" style="display: none;">
                    <option>تليفون</option>
                    <option>الايميل</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control SearchInput" name="Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group CloneBtn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="الموردون"/>
</form>
```

and This is the controller:

```cs
public IActionResult SaveBranch(Store store)
{
    var isSucceed = Store.AddStore(store);
    return isSucceed ? AddSupplier() :  AddBranch("Error");
}
```

I Expected the actual output an object of Store with list of contact info and MainBranch with another list of contact info inside it and address.

The result was only main info of Store supplied and the rest is nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set correct `asp-for` attribute or name attribute for your input and select.If you have a list, then you need to specify their index also like `asp-for="StoreContact[0].ContactValue"`

A simple demo shown below:

```
@model Store
<form asp-controller="Onboarding" asp-action="SaveBranch" method="post" >
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Image" class="form-control" />
    </div>      
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">StoreContact1 ContactValue</label>
        <input asp-for="StoreContact[0].ContactValue" class="form-control" />

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">StoreContact2 ContactValue</label>
        <input asp-for="StoreContact[1].ContactValue" class="form-control" />

    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">MainBranch Title</label>
        <input asp-for="MainBranch.Title" class="form-control" />

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">MainBranch City</label>
        <select asp-for="MainBranch.MainAddress.City.CityName" class="form-control" >
          <option>...</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```